# How to perform a single aggregation task on GAE once a given set of fan-out tasks complete

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

The workflow I'm trying to build is this,
Enqueue many related tasks to run in parallel (at least several thousand)
Once all related jobs finish have a finalization job execute

I can't figure out how to get that single finalization job to execute. I'd like this task to execute asap after all the related tasks finish. However, the only thing I can think of is to resort to a single threaded polling job which checks if all tasks have finished, and enqueues the finalization task.

I've looked at the pipeline documentation https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/ and I've watched http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/high-throughput-data-pipelines-appengine.html which at first seemed promising but haven't been able to find a good solution from that.

After considering the pipeline library some more I think I see a pattern that could be used to scale the waited for jobs to the high number I'm wanting.

Have a batch enqueueing job this job enqueues a batch of the tasks at a time, then starts another batch enqueuing job which waits on the enqueued batch to complete. Finally, if there are no more batches to execute, the aggregator job is run.

Is that the pattern to be using for large numbers of waited on jobs?

Comment: That is exactly what the pipelines library is for. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: In relation to the pipeline library the WaitFor syntax is functionally what I want. However, reading the documentation I don't see how it should be used at the scale of thousands of waited for jobs since the JobSettings is a vararg on the final job. Thousands of varargs doesn't seem like a good plan.

Comment: I've edited the original post with a possible solution to the problem I had with the pipeline library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never posted this description since I hadn't implemented it yet, but the following is a high level description of how a single task can be executed after a large number of required tasks complete on a system such as GAE without depending on a third party framework.

### Fan Out

1. fanoutCount = # of fan out tasks
2. Create and commit table entry with fanoutCount = #, completeCount=0, Byte array with a number of bits = to the fanoutCount

   - Since the max table size is 1Mb, this will support millions of jobs. Still might be safest to have an upper limit
3. Iterate over the tasks, enqueing them with the entity key, and a task index (incremented count)

   - You might want to implement a strategy to recover a partially done fanout task. Tasks must be idempotent, so could just re-start if the same work is identified each time

### Task Consumer

1. Perform whatever business logic is desired, I've assumed the entity key is a sufficient identifier
2. enqueue entry back to a fan in queue with the Job entry record id, and the task index
3. Note: Task idempotency. There is no guarantee a task won't execute more than once. Can either

   - a) Execute business logic and final queue message in a transaction, checking inside that the business logic has not already been performed
   - b) Make individual business logic steps idempotent (fan in will ignore duplicate messages)

### Fan In

1. Consume the fan in queue
2. In transaction

   - Get the table entry (candidate for simple caching),
   - Set the bit of the array corresponding to the task index to 1 (if it was already 1 we are double processing, just continue)
   - Increment the completeCount,
   - if completeCount == fanoutCount
     enqueu your finalization job
   - Commit transaction
3. Note: Concurrency. The entry can only take soo many transactions soo fast. The logic itself is simple though.
                  Consider processing batch messages, with low (or no) concurrency. Especially if you only have 1 fan out executing at a time

Comment: do you have any example or reference on how to implement the Fan-In and Fan-Out mechanism?

Comment: The code which initiated the comment way back when wasn't public. For a small Fan-Out Fan-In you can use the original pipeline library under discussion. Should be examples available for that. Unfortunately there is not a public implementation of code for the description I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for each batch to complete makes your process much more serial - it will take longer to run that way.

If high numbers of varargs are a problem, as a workaround you could have a fan-in task corresponding to each fan-out, assuming fan-out doesn't branch more than about 10 tasks at a time.

Comment: If I only had a 10 task fan out I'd simply use the WaitFor syntax of the pipeline library and wait on all 10 jobs. 

As is I'm starting up a batch of 100, waiting for that batch to finish before I queue up another batch, until I finally have no more batches, then i run my finalization work. Working fairly well so far.

Comment: By 10 task fan out, I mean the branching factor.  Basically, suggesting you start all the batches of 100 in parallel, waiting for all batches to finish, and then within each batch, start 100 tasks and wait for them.  (assuming you have <100 batches)